# Manual Rotation

Tags: ios

I have rather complicated user interface for my application that supports both Portrait & Landscape orientations (excluding PortraitUpsideDown). There are two View Controllers and thus two Views. The first one represents Portrait UI and the other Landscape. Both controllers are related with the same class. I have created two Outlets for each kind of orientation and several Outlet Collections for other UI objects. The code that I use for animating the rotation is below.

This is how I declare those properties.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *landscape;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *portrait;
```

And the process of animation.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        self.view = self.portrait;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadius(0));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0);
    } else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.view = self.landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadius(-90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 568.0, 300.0);
    } else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.view = self.landscape;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadius(90));
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 568.0, 300.0);
    }
}
```

The problem is being that the second (landscape) view doesn't exist neither at the moment of rotation nor at the moment of View's loading. Code samples that I use as an example don't work for me due to this issue. As well as I understand the thing, the second View isn't automatically loaded and I should do something about that in my ViewController...

Please help me solve that problem! Thank you in advance!

P.S. Everything works fine with using a simple .XIB file for managing UI. I just simply drag two Views and it's okay because they are both handled by the same controller. So what do I do for my Storyboard?

Comment: This is not the way to implement rotation support. You should let the UIViewControllers manage it for you.

Comment: Actually, this is a working way. But since I have 2 Views I have to manage all the animation processes manually by simple using CoreGraphics Framework. 

I wonder why isn't one of my View being created at the moment of initial View loading...